# Are there any other semi/portable ways to dynamically allocate memory?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

this:

```
char *buf = NULL;
scanf("%ms", &buf);
```

will get a dynamically allocated char buffer. I know this is limited to code compiled with Gcc (and specifically version 2.7 of glibc).

I am also aware that the "correct" and portable way is to just use `malloc()` (and friends) to get the memory.

I'm curious however, are there any other portable or semi-portable<sup>*</sup> implementations out there for getting dynamically allocated memory? I find tricks and tips of memory allocation in C a hard topic to "Google".

**Note:** This is not "required" for anything, so there are no limitations on answers.

<sub>* semi-portable meaning "if you compile the same way I do, this will work"</sub>

Comment: Do `sbrk()` or `mmap()` count?

Comment: BTW, add `&` to `scanf("%ms", &buf);`

Comment: @VladLazarenko - `mmap()` doesn't allocate memory does it?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL - oops, typing too fast. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Are you talking about a another way to read a word into a dynamically allocated string, or something more general?

Comment: @VaughnCato -  "implementations out there for **getting** dynamically allocated memory", so `sbrk()` and `brk()` I do count

Comment: You are trying to find ways to reduce the number of calls to malloc in your code?

Comment: @VaughnCato - Consider it an investigation into memory allocation tools. I'm trying to learn about functions that can do memory allocation in C code which I was not previously aware of. The end result may indeed be simplified code and/or less calls to `malloc` depending on the situation that I'm coding for. As I mentioned before `This is not "required" for anything` right now.

Comment: Ok, so would `strdup` count, since it allocates memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX has

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

and

```
ssize_t getdelim(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim, FILE *stream);
```

which should qualify as semi-portable.

Comment: `If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer` - Nice. I think that's even more portable than my gcc example.

Comment: And "If the buffer is not large  enough  to  hold the line, `getline()` resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary." for even more convenience.