# sscanf with pipes C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I have a problem parsing in c with sscanf

I read a text on console with one function called read_line()

```
char cm1[100],cm2[100],cm3[100]
printf("Enter command:");
read_line(var_text);
/*var_text = cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 d: | sort */
int num = sscanf(var_text,"%s | %s | %s",cm1,cm2,cm3);
```

Ok if i write in `var_text cat | cut | sort` in cm1 return cat in cm2 return cut and in cm3 return sort, but if i write `cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 d: | sort` , cm1 return cat and cm2 and cm3 none...

I'm made a shell in c, and i need the commands and atributes

Thx for all, and sorry for that bad english :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier will stop processing at the first whitespace character. In the case of:

> cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 d: | sort

it will be the space after the `cat` at which the first `%s` will end. The format specifier then expects a `|` which does not exist and `cm2` and `cm3` are not populated. You could use a scanset to achieve this:

```
if (3 == sscanf(var_text, "%99[^|]| %99[^|]| %99s", cm1, cm2, cm3))
{
}
```

Note use of width specifier to prevent buffer overrun and checking of return value from `sscanf()` to ensure all target variables were populated.

The format specifier `%99[^|]` is stating read at most 99 characters (one less than the target buffer size to accomodate the null terminator) until a `|` character is encountered.

See demo at http://ideone.com/Cz1Qef .

Comment: you can use `sscanf(var_text, "%m[^|] | %m[^|] | %ms", &cm1, &cm2, &cm3);` this avoid the problem of buffer overflow.  the cmx should be define as `char *` and do not forget to free the memory

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL, I am unfamiliar with `%m` and cannot find it in the C99 standard. Is it a compiler extension?

Comment: it's not valid for all gcc version see the following link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863063/are-there-any-other-semi-portable-ways-to-dynamically-allocate-memory

Comment: when using `%m` than the sscanf will allocate memory